# Ionic 2 app starting with white space and delay

Tags: ionic-framework

I have developed ionic 2 calendar app. when start this app via phone it gets white screen for a while like 1 min first and take more time to start my app. How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the app in production mode to speed up and optimize the start of your application

If you're in an ionic 2 app, you can enable this by doing the following,

**open src/app/main.ts**

Import enableProdMode from Angular 2 core

```
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
```

Then call the enableProdMode() function before bootstraping your module

```
enableProdMode();

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

and now while running the app through cli try adding a flag like "**--prod**"

ionic run android --prod
In ionic 3.x, you don't have to enable anything in the code. you can simply run it using the cli command,

```
ionic cordova run android --prod
```

check this documentation from [angular.io](https://angular.io/api/core/enableProdMode)

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much  for your immediate response

Comment: what version of ionic are you using? try the command "ionic info" for details

Comment: I am using 2.2 ionic version

Comment: could you update your main.ts file from src/app/main.ts?